# Passing output from dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently I have a working version of a dynamic SQL query without any variables except one (`@ColumnHeader`). And am able to get the desired result being a collection of column names in one line separated by comma.

```
select @ColumnHeader = COALESCE(@ColumnHeader+',','') + '''' + column_name + '''' 
from databaseName.Information_Schema.Columns
where table_name = 'Dates'
```

I am trying to add variables for `Database_information_schema` and `TableName`.

```
DECLARE @ColumnHeader varchar(8000) 
DECLARE @Database_Information_SchemaColumns varchar(8000) = 'DatabaseName2.Information_Schema.Columns'
DECLARE @TableName varchar(8000) = 'dates'

DECLARE @sqlQuery as nvarchar(max) = 'Select ' + @ColumnHeader + '= COALESCE(' + @ColumnHeader+ +''','','''')+ ''''''''+column_name+'''''''' from ' + @Database_Information_SchemaColumns + 'where table_name = '''+ @TableName + ''''

Print @sqlQuery

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery;
```

I am getting `Null` values and am not sure whats wrong here.

Comment: If you are using a modern version of SQL Server (2017 or later) you can use [`string_agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to build the comma-delimited list.

Comment: Currently using 2012

Answer (score 5):

What follows is some working code. I explain the changes required:

1. You are trying to assign a parameter using dynamic SQL, therefore the parameter needs to be part of the dynamic SQL string, not concatenated with it.
2. To assign a parameter using dynamic SQL you have to pass it in/out of `sp_executesql` because the context the dynamic SQL is running under cannot see the parameters declared.
3. While this is not necessary, I have renamed the internal parameter so that its clear which parameter belongs in which scope. However both could use the same name if desired.
4. You were missing a space before your `where`.
5. I recommend using `varchar(max)` and `nvarchar(max)` as there is no need to risk running into the 8k limit.
6. Use `quotename` for any database, schema, table or column names to protect against injection.
7. Use the `sysname` datatype where a system name is being stored
8. Split all system names into parts to allow the use of `quotename`

```
    DECLARE @ColumnHeader varchar(max) 
        , @Database_Information_Database sysname = 'DatabaseName2'
        , @Database_Information_Schema sysname = 'Information_Schema'
        , @Database_Information_Columns sysname = 'Columns'
        , @TableName sysname = 'dates';

    DECLARE @sqlQuery nvarchar(max) = 'select @ColumnHeaderInteral = COALESCE(@ColumnHeaderInteral,'','','''') + '''''''' + column_name + '''''''' from '
        + quotename(@Database_Information_Database) + '.'
        + quotename(@Database_Information_Schema) + '.'
        + quotename(@Database_Information_Columns)
        + ' where quotename(table_name) = ''' + quotename(@TableName) + '''';

    PRINT @sqlQuery;

    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery, N'@ColumnHeaderInteral varchar(max) output', @ColumnHeaderInteral = @ColumnHeader out;

    SELECT @ColumnHeader;
```

[Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: A couple extra recommendations: Use `sysname` as the data type for injected object names and split them into their individual parts (database, schema, table, column) and quote them properly with `QUOTENAME` to avoid unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Dale Yes it is working. What I find strange is that if I use this and ran the query in SSMS. It works. but if I use it in job (Type - TSQL), it returns

Invalid column name 'column_name'.